# Is there a closed-form result for $\int_0^{\infty } e^{-\frac{n^2}{a (b+n)}-\frac{a(b+n)}{n}} \, dn$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there a closed-form result for $\int_0^{\infty } e^{-\frac{n^2}{a (b+n)}-\frac{a(b+n)}{n}} \, dn$?

I have checked the Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, but no prototype fits this integrate. To the Best of My Ability, I can not find the closed-form result of the integrate. Can it be solved into a closed-form result?

Answer (score 1):

By assuming $a,b>0$ and setting $\frac{n}{a(b+n)}=x$ the given integral becomes

$$ ab\int_{0}^{1/a}\exp\left(-x-\frac{ab}{1-ax}\right)\frac{dx}{(1-ax)^2} = be^{-1/a}\int_{0}^{1}\exp\left(\frac{x}{a}-\frac{ab}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{x^2}$$
or:
$$ be^{-1/a}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-ab x+\frac{1}{ax}\right)\,dx $$
that does not have a nice closed form, but admits simple numerical approximations we may get by assuming that $\frac{1}{ax}$ is approximately constant on short intervals. For instance it is trivial that

$$ be^{-1/a}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-ab x+\frac{1}{ax}\right)\,dx \leq be^{-1/a}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-ab x+\frac{1}{a}\right)\,dx =\frac{1}{a e^{ab}}. $$

Comment: $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-ab x+\frac{1}{ax}\right)\,dx$ can be considered as the incomplete Bessel function $K_{-1}(ab,-1/a)$  (also called leaky aquifer function). See this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242980699_Incomplete_Bessel_generalized_incomplete_gamma_or_leaky_aquifer_functions)  by Harris, for example, where  several numerical calculations techniques are given.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it! However, when set $x=\frac{n}{a (b+n)}$, we have $n=\frac{a b x}{1-a x}$, then $\frac{dn}{dx}=\frac{a^2 b x}{(1-a x)^2}+\frac{a b}{1-a x}$. After some simplification, I can not obtain the result of the first step in the answer. Thank you again for your help! Is there another way to obtain a closed-form result, the approximate one is also great!

Comment: @EricLou: Even if the integral's upper limit were to remain $\infty$ after the change of variable, you'd still need [special functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) to express its value. As it stands, even these are insufficient (unless, of course, one were to invent *incomplete* versions of them, such as has already been done in the past in the case of the [beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) and [$\Gamma$ functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)).